# Placeholder Adopting from Previous Text Field

Tags: cocoa

Quick question! When any NSFormCell becomes the first responder, its placeholder text becomes that of the last NSTextField to have focus. Here's an illustration: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4ekv.jpg

However, the NSTextFields never encounter this! Have you seen this before? This is happening in Xcode 4.3 — what thoughts do you have?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using bindings? How are the bindings set up? If not bindings, how are the form and its cells set up?

Comment: @KenThomases Thank you for your reply! I'm not using bindings. The form is inside of a TabView while the TextFields are not. All attributes of this form are declared in the form's Attributes tab — nothing in the form is generated dynamically. The placeholder texts of the TextFields are generated dynamically with today's date, but the problem remains even without that code!

Comment: Have you set placeholders for the form cells or the prototype cell? What happens if you do? Are you using a delegate for the text field or the form? Have you implemented any of the text-related delegate methods? Are you customizing the field editor for the window?

Comment: I should let you know this happens to me in every new project! I set the placeholders for the form cells, but I haven't dealt with prototype cells. I'm not using a delegate for either. Nothing is custom. Should I be explicitly setting a delegate and using these methods? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an answer, but just some further observations.

I did some experimenting with this, and it's not anything you're doing.  If you just drag a form and a text field into a window in IB, and put a placeholder string in the text field, then that placeholder appears in the form if you first select the text field and then one of the form cells (with no code at all in the app).  It doesn't matter whether you put any placeholder in the form in IB, it still gets the one from the text field.  I also put a button in the window with an action that logs the placeholderString of one of the cells -- it always logs null, even though it shows the text field's placeholder.  If you put a placeholder in that cell (in IB), then it logs that placeholder, but if you select the text field and then that cell, the text field's placeholder shows up, but the log still shows the original placeholder.

This looks like a bug to me.  It might have something to do with the field editor?  Isn't there a shared field editor for all text fields in a view?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like the field editor has stale info. The form cells ought to reset the field editor's placeholder text when they get focus, but it sounds like they're not. Perhaps setting a delegate on the form and implementing `-controlTextDidBeginEditing:` to reset the placeholder string at that point would help.